# c++ rand() and RNG from boost generating the same numbers(in release mode) even with srand(0)

Tags: c++, boost, random

I was using rand() to produce some random numbers inside a function to populate some arrays but when I ran the program I noticed it was giving always the same row of generated numbers. The arrays were filled with the same row of generated numbers, it could be all 0 or a row with different numbers, but this pattern of numbers were the same in every array.

So I used debug to run the program step by step and it worked, rand() were generating different numbers to every array..

After this I decided to try another method to generate random numbers. I found a way to do this using Boost library.

This is the code I'm using now:

```
int main(){
    typedef boost::mt19937 RNGType;
    RNGType rng( (unsigned int)time(NULL));
    boost::uniform_int<> one_to_six( 1, 6);
    boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::uniform_int<> >
    dice(rng, one_to_six);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<dice()<<std::endl;   
    }
}
```

If I use this code on main() function, everything goes well and it gives me 10 random numbers.
But if I put this code in a function to call it whenever I want it returns me the same number. Always 55555555, or 0000000..
Fun fact is, if I use debug and make a breakpoint at that function and run it step by step, it works again giving me always different numbers. 
So I don't know what I'm missing here..

**edit**: When I used rand() I was using **srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));**

**update 1:**

```
    int random(int begin,int end){
    typedef boost::mt19937 RNGType;
    RNGType rng( (unsigned int)time(NULL));
    boost::uniform_int<> one_to_six( begin , end );
    boost::variate_generator< RNGType, boost::uniform_int<> >
    dice(rng, one_to_six);
    return dice();
}


int main()       {
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    cout<<random(0,6)<<endl;

}
```

If I use this method it will give me the same sequence. If I run it step by step with debug it will work and give me different numbers.

Comment: _"even with `srand(0)`"_ It's purposed to yield the same numbers again, you should use something like `srand(time(0));`

Comment: sry I didn't mention but I'm using on the code above aswell:  (unsigned int)time(NULL)

Comment: @Rdz `If I use this code on main() function, everything goes well and it gives me 10 random numbers. But if I put this code in a function`... Then why not show us the version of the code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The seconds returned by `time(NULL)` increments only once per second (funny, that). If you're seeding more than once per second, you will get the same sequence.

Comment: So if I call it by function it will seed every time I call it, If I use it on main() it will only seed one time.. So that may be the problem. So in that case it would be hard to use it within a fucntion.. That seeding should be static

Comment: @Rdz: That's definitely the problem. And yes you would have to pass a reference to the generator into the function.

Comment: @Rdz You can use it in a function, just pass the seed to the function and have the caller generate the seed some sane way, such as by calling `rand`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another way, and it's working now.

I'll let the code here if someone needs

```
boost::random::mt19937 gen;

int random(int begin, int end) 
{   
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(begin, end);
    return dist(gen);
}
int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        std::cout << random(0,20) << std::endl;  
 }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `generate_random_number` , you don't call it

Answer (score 0):

You seed the rng in every function call, therefore you always get a random sequence (of length 1) starting from a seed. Since you use `time(NULL)` as the seed, all calls within a second will get the same seed and therefore the same sequence.

Since you don't want to have the same sequence repeatedly, you should not seed the rng between calls to `random` but instead continue the sequence from previous call, just like you do in the version that is entirely inside `main`. That requires you to maintain the state of the generator object between the calls instead of constructing a new one every time.